# How is a double loop implemented in Elixir?

Tags: for-loop, elixir

How is a double for loop implemented in Elixir?

I was interested in writing a double for loop to compare a naiveSort to a quickSort implementation.

Then I realized I don't even know how to write a double for loop in elixir!

So, how is a double for loop written in Elixir? Keep in mind I'm trying to do a naiveSort...

Comment: recursion is used in erlang/elixir rather than loops. Plenty of examples in the Enum module of Elixir or the :lists module of erlang.

Comment: I'm putting this as a comment because I don't KNOW the answer, but this gave me perspective this morning. I'm learning Elixir for a project at work and I'm finding the vast shift in paradigm refreshing. http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/recursion.html

Comment: Or maybe you could use comprehensions.

Answer (score 2):

An idiomatic way to do this might use list comprehensions like:

```
defmodule Quick do
  def sort([first | rest]) do
    sort(for(n <- rest, n < first, do: n)) ++
    [first] ++
    sort(for(n <- rest, n >= first, do: n))
  end

  def sort([]) do
    []
  end
end

iex(5)> Quick.sort [5,4,3,2,1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Of course quick sort lends itself quite nicely to a recursive solution since the algorithm is "sort all the items smaller than me, then add me, then add all the items larger than me".  Which is expressed very nearly in Elixir (and Erlang).

The `for` is a list comprehension.  It builds a list based upon a generator (the `n <- rest` part and a filter (the `n < first` part).

Comment: Seems like your implementation of quicksort goes over every element in the array twice, which is unnecessary. Can list comprehension be used to create 2 separate lists ?

Comment: Also quick sort choose an element randomly in the middle of the list, how is that done in elixir?